# css / position main content div to right of login and register div

Tags: html, css, position, css-float, sticky-footer

I am trying to create a page with a header, sticky footer, and three divs in between. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my html and css:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ONE DAY ONLY</title>
    <script src="reqscripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/application.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>ONE DAY ONLY</h1>
            <p>THE BIZZ()</p>
        </header>
        <div id="login"></div>
        <div id="register"></div>
        <div id="main"><p>Content</p></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css/application.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    background: rgba(179,180,255,1);
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}

.footer {
    background: rgba(22,138,43,1);
}

#loginform {
    width: 240px;
    height: 165px;
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
}

#registerform {
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
}

#loginuser, #loginpass, #reguser, #regpass, #regemail {
    float: right;
}

#submitbutton, #registerbutton {
    text-align: center;
}

.textaligncenter {
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
    background: rgba(179,180,255,1);
    height: 90px;
}

#main {
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
}
```

I have tried adding `float: right` to the main div, and for some reason it floats it right, but into the footer div. I want the main div (with "Content") to be positioned nicely to the right of the login and register divs.

I used this for my sticky footer:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

**UPDATE**

Per the suggestion below, the page now looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I got the div to be positioned where I want, but when I add a bunch of line breaks to extend the main div...it extends over the stickyfooter...which shouldnt happen...

Here is what I changed:

```
#main {
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
    float: left;

}

#loginregcss {
    float: left;
}

#content {
    float: left;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ONE DAY ONLY</title>
    <script src="reqscripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/application.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>ONE DAY ONLY</h1>
            <p>THE BIZZ()</p>
        </header>
        <div id="loginregcss">
            <div id="login"></div>
            <div id="register"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="main"><p>Content</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys... I needed `clear: both;` for `.footer` and `.push` - as suggested here - http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">    
        <div id="left">
            <div id="login"></div>
            <div id="register"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="main"><p>Content</p></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>


#left{
 width: 250px;
 float: left;
}

#main{
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;   
}
```

To get the footer always at the bottom:

```
.push{
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response...it is being positioned in the footer now...i will take a screen shot and post it above to show you.

Comment: I think you forgot to close a div somewhere cause it should work

Comment: i did something else that made it work - but now the main div extends over the footer...ill post another picture and what i changed.

Answer (score 0):

try this steps:
move both login and register to a div like this:

```
        <div class="leftBar">
           <div id="login"></div>
           <div id="register"></div>
        </div>
```

and add left float to class leftBar and main. add a little margin-right to this leftBar. A complete code is here:

```
<title>ONE DAY ONLY</title>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>ONE DAY ONLY</h1>
            <p>THE BIZZ()</p>
        </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftBar">
           <div id="login"></div>
           <div id="register"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="main"><p>Content</p></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
```

and here the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    background: rgba(179,180,255,1);
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 600px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}

.footer {
    background: rgba(22,138,43,1);
    width:100%;
}
.leftBar{
    float:left ;
    width:28%;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#login {
    width: 240px;
    height: 165px;
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
}
#register {
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
}

#loginuser, #loginpass, #reguser, #regpass, #regemail {
    float: right;
}

#submitbutton, #registerbutton {
    text-align: center;
}

.textaligncenter {
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
    background: rgba(179,180,255,1);
    height: 90px;
}
.row{
    width:100%;
}
#main {
    background: rgba(207,207,255, 1);
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

SEE THIS [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/NZ6vS/3/)

Comment: extend the result view to see it. i think i should make a little more change, so i will do it and comment here when its done.

Comment: this is not what i am trying to do...i dont want the footer to always be visible...i just want it to always be at the bottom i.e. NOT "position: fixed"